# symfony service constructor called multiple times

Tags: php, symfony, service, constructor, scope

I've read about symfony service documentation, and understood that by default when creating a service, it will be created at container scope, and will be construct one time only (if requested at least once).

I've added some logs in my service constructor, and noticed that the constructor is called multiple times: I'm refreshing my web page that called an action in my controller. This action get my service and use it.
Each time i refresh my web page, the service constructor is called and logged.
I'm using Symfony 2.1
Is it normal? What did i miss?

Thanks in advance for your feedback

Comment: show some codes please..

Comment: yes ! show us some code :D

Comment: maybe you use twig render or render_esi methods which causes multiple requests made?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's completely normal for PHP because PHP is [interpreted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) programing language. So, PHP code is interpreted by a web server with a PHP processor module each time you request (for example when you refresh page) a server.

You should read more about [Symfony2 and HTTP Fundamentals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html)

Comment: ok, thank you. So why the symfony documentation says that in container scope the service is instantiated one time only?

Comment: @user3544352 Doc says: `The same instance is used each time you *request it from this container*.` not each HTTP request : ) Please pay attention of Symfony2 application flow: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#the-symfony-application-flow

Comment: thank you. I think i finally got it, and i will read again the documentation to fix it :). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I have some extra input for those willing to understand what's going on.

Yes, services are instantiated only once. But they are instantiated **per request**. The most important thing you should notice is who initiated the request. The bundle (I assume) most of us have installed is the [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) bundle.

It does it magic, but it has to call back to the server to get the exposed routes from it's own `ExposedRoutesExtractor`. That's how your service gets initialised more than once

Put a breakpoint in the service's constructor and take a look at `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable each time the breakpoint is hit. You'll notice something like this:

1. `<your_own_uri>` <- Your initial request
2. `/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData` <- [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)
3. `/_wdt/c7becf` <- [WebProfilerBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html)

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Services are singletons, so always only one instance can exists.

Answer (score 1):

You may be calling the service twice (or more) in your code. But as general rule and according to the latest [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container) (3.1):

> When you ask for the `app.mailer` service from the container, the container constructs the object and returns it. This is another major advantage of using the service container. Namely, **a service is never constructed until it's needed. If you define a service and never use it on a request, the service is never created**.